# Paging is not going beyond 270 pages

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

The following code uses jqxgrid plugins. I changes loop value to 400, to generate 400 pages with 10 pages per page.

When run I only see 0-26 links (for 270 pages), instead of 0-39 links. How can I fix this please?

I another scenario, in my application, I only see paging links for 380 pages instead 900 pages. If anyone could fix, the following I'd be able to apply same solution in my application. Thanks so much!

---

The earlier code has been modified, to use the example from:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/virtualdata.htm?classic

Why doesn't it display records? Please explain. What is the change required. Thanks so much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>In this demo jqxGrid uses a virtualized paging which enables you to handle very large data sets without any impact on client side performance.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var theme = getTheme();
            // prepare the data
            var data = new Array();
            var jsonObject = { "contactList":[

{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},
{"age":1,"SId":"S1234567","gender":"male"},

], "totalrecords":9};

//alert("jsonObject.totalrecords : " + jsonObject.totalrecords);

            // generate sample data.
            var generatedata = function (startindex, endindex) {
                var data = {};
                for (var i = startindex; i < endindex; i++) {

            //alert(startindex + " " + endindex);
                    var row = {};

                            row["age"] = jsonObject.contactList[i].age;
                            row["gender"] = jsonObject.contactList[i].gender;
                            row["SId"] = jsonObject.contactList[i].SId;


                    data[i] = row;
                }
                return data;
            }
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "array",
                localdata: {},
                totalrecords: jsonObject.totalrecords
            };

            // load virtual data.
            var rendergridrows = function (params) {

        alert("rendergridrows : " + source.totalrecords);
        //alert("rendergridrows : " + params.startindex + " " + params.endindex);
                var data = generatedata(params.startindex, params.endindex);
                return data;
            }
            var totalcolumnrenderer = function (row, column, cellvalue) {
                var cellvalue = $.jqx.dataFormat.formatnumber(cellvalue, 'c2');
                return '<span style="margin: 6px 3px; font-size: 12px; float: right; font-weight: bold;">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
            }
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 670,
                autoheight: true,
                source: dataAdapter,
                theme: theme,
                virtualmode: true,
                pageable: true,
                rendergridrows: rendergridrows,
                columns: [

                          { text: 'Age', datafield: 'age', width: 50 },
                          { text: 'SId', datafield: 'SId', width: 120 },
                          { text: 'Gender', datafield: 'gender', width: 80 },

                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see from your code, you add anchor for each page. I do not think there would be enough space in the DIV tag for so many tags. Consider using a different layout like an input field for selecting the page as in this sample with 1 million records: [virtualdata.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/virtualdata.htm?classic)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used same example. Why doesn't the code display records.

Comment: I have modified as per your answer and re-posted the code. Please see above. Why doesn't it display records.

Comment: It is just a notification message.

Comment: @dave-newton: can you take a look, please.

Comment: @aleksandr-m : can you take look as well, please? Thanks.